# ask with a where - I cannot find the syntax

Tags: netlogo

here is what I would like to write in netlogo, but cannot seem to find the syntax

```
ask where [ param > threshold] turtles  [
  ]
```

I want to return the agent-set, but I cannot find the correct syntax to make this work

Comment: I think the question is not very clear: what do you mean with where?

Comment: Sorry for double comment, I accidentally sent the previous one before completing it and then lost my connection, so cannot edit.
By the way, if what you intend to do is to address only those turtles whose turtles-own variable `param` is greater than `threshold`, then `with` is what you're looking for; the use of `with` is described in the NetLogo Dictionary.

Comment: Just FYI, basics like this are covered in [the NetLogo programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html), and this particular topic is in [the Agentsets sections](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#agentsets).

Answer (score 1):

as Matteo notes in the comments, you appear to be after `with`, so the syntax would be:

```
ask turtles with [param > threshold]
[  ; do something
]
```